# Having trouble toggling the class of elements in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, class, foreach

Im trying to toggle the "done" class of the elements in an array on click but I keep getting error messages saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: classList is not defined". When I try to console.log("testing") on clicking it works so I know I'm close I just cant figure it out.

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function toggleDone() {
    classList.toggle("done");
}

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener("click", toggleDone);
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);




<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li><button id="delete">Delete</button>
        <li>Jello</li><button id="delete">Delete</button>
        <li>Spinach</li><button id="delete">Delete</button>
        <li>Rice</li><button id="delete">Delete</button>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li><button id="delete">Delete</button>
        <li>Candles</li><button id="delete">Delete</button>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: What is `classList` inside `toggleDone`?

Comment: Please provide the corresponding HTML code.

Comment: The proper usage for classList is `Element.classList`. Your code would probably be `li.classList`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: You're using `toggleDone` in `addEventListener`, your function should be like `function toggleDone(event) { event.target.classList.toggle("done"); }`

Comment: Whoops, tried it with li but I wind up getting an error message saying that toggle is undefined rather than classList

Comment: kiner you are a lifesaver, thank you!